# Cannot connect to my l3 switch from pc

Tags: switch, ping, hp

I tried to connect to my HP V1910 Switch; I tried with a console cable and putty but I get only a black screen and can't do anything. I also tried to use the default ip address printed on the switch, using putty(both telnet and ssh), but always get the following black screen and can't do anything about it.
[image]

putty 
After ping failed, I checked with nmap -Pn to check if the switch is visible to the network and it's up:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the baud rate to 38400 while using the console cable.
[image]